# Python: Grouping Multiple Lists Based On Same Element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a tab separated text file like given below:

```
23      Hello How are you?
23      What's up?
24      I am using Python
```

I want to separate and group the above data so that it looks like this:

```
23      Hello How are you? What's up?
24      I am using Python
```

Basically I want to group the text with the same value of the first column (and then write them into separate text files of 23.txt and 24.txt)

I have the code as written below:

```
def data_extraction(inputfile):

ifile = open(inputfile, "r")
lines = ifile.readlines()


for value in lines:
    each_line = value.split('\t')
    service_order = each_line[0]
    text = each_line[-1]
```

The above will give me multiple lists (`value = ['23', 'Hello How are you?']`  and so on) inside the for loop. What do I need to do group the same column and their corresponding texts?

Comment: Is the file sorted on the first column?

Comment: Its not sorted. The first column are random numbers. They are actually order numbers in the original file that I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> data = """23\tHello How are you?
23\tWhat's up?
24\tI am using Python"""
>>> new_dict = defaultdict(str)
>>> data = data.split('\n')
>>> for line in data:
    each_line = line.split('\t')
    new_dict[int(each_line[0])] += " " + each_line[-1]

>>> print new_dict
defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {24: ' I am using Python', 23: " Hello How are you? What's up?"})
```

Output -

```
>>> for key in sorted(new_dict):
    print str(key) + "\t" + new_dict[key].strip()


23  Hello How are you? What's up?
24  I am using Python
```

You should also not use `readlines` and read the line one by one and use a context while reading the file.

```
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Use the above code
```

Comment: if your using appending string  y u need to take default dict . you can use general dict right :)

Comment: So that I get an empty string for the first time. I could do the same with `dict.get` though.

Answer (score 2):

```
ifile = open(inputfile, "r")

linedic=defaultdict(list,{})

for line in ifile:
    line=line.split(None,1)
    linedic[line[0].strip()].append(line[1].strip())
    #linedic[line[0].strip()]+=" "+line[1].strip()
```

you a default dict for this whose key is line number and values are the text

Comment: You could also `line.split(None, 1)` to be sure, you get it split only once.